# Spring Kafka Template - Connect to Kafka Topic on Spring Boot Startup

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have implemented a basic Spring Boot Application which uses Spring Kafka. I want my producer to connect to the Kafka Topic before the first `.send()` is called but I can't find a way to do so. Is that possible?

Logs to show that KafkaTemplate only connects to the Kafka Topic after I trigger the `.send` method at `16:12:44`:

```
2021-11-24 16:12:12.602  INFO 63930 --- [           main] c.e.k.KafkaProducerExampleApplication    : The following profiles are active: dev
2021-11-24 16:12:13.551  INFO 63930 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-11-24 16:12:13.559  INFO 63930 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-11-24 16:12:13.559  INFO 63930 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
2021-11-24 16:12:13.613  INFO 63930 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-11-24 16:12:13.613  INFO 63930 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 974 ms
2021-11-24 16:12:13.989  INFO 63930 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
2021-11-24 16:12:14.190  INFO 63930 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-11-24 16:12:14.190  INFO 63930 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2021-11-24 16:12:14.207  INFO 63930 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2021-11-24 16:12:14.239  INFO 63930 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2021-11-24 16:12:14.336  INFO 63930 --- [           main] c.e.k.KafkaProducerExampleApplication    : Started KafkaProducerExampleApplication in 7.055 seconds (JVM running for 7.341)
2021-11-24 16:12:44.550  INFO 63930 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-24 16:12:44.550  INFO 63930 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-24 16:12:44.551  INFO 63930 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2021-11-24 16:12:44.649  INFO 63930 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `non-transactional producer` (transactionIdPrefix is not supplied), when you first call KafkaTemplate.send, it will delegate to `ProducerFactory` to get a **single instance** of `Producer`. At this time, because there's no a **single instance** of `Producer` before, `ProducerFactory` will create this one for you (that's why you saw the log `ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values ...`). This **producer instance** is now used/shared by all clients.

---

So if you want to create **the above producer instance** beforehand, you could directly call it on the `ProducerFactory`, e.g:

```java
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaProducerFactory) {
        KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate(kafkaProducerFactory);
        kafkaProducerFactory.createProducer();
        return kafkaTemplate;
...
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to connect to the broker in a bean definition - it is too early in the application context's lifecycle - it is better to implement `SmartLifecycle` in one of your beans and establish the connection in `start()`.

Comment: Thank Mr. @GaryRussell for pointing that out. Could you give an example of that? I'm not good at SpringCore, so I don't really figure it out. Or could you post another answer?, I'll delete mine.

Comment: See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding Linh Vu's answer, it's best not to create a connection in a bean definition - it's too early in the application context's lifecycle.

Instead, add a bean that implements `SmartLifecycle` and create the connection in `start()`; that way, the context will be completely initialized before connecting.

```java
@Bean
SmartLifecycle connector(ProducerFactory<Object ,Object> pf) {
    return new SmartLifecycle() {
        
        @Override
        public void stop() {
        }
        
        @Override
        public void start() {
            pf.createProducer().close();
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean isRunning() {
            return false;
        }
        
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Gary, may I know what it means by it being too early in the application context's lifecycle? What kind of problems will happen if I connect in the Bean definition? Thank you.

Comment: It's probably harmless in this case, but it is just best practice; there are three distinct phases of application context initialization - collect bean definitions, instantiate all the beans, start any `SmartLifecycle` beans; if you start performing activity such as connecting to external servers in phase 2, not all beans may be available.

Answer (score 0):

`SmartLifecycle` bean works for us, thanks.

```
@Component
class KafkaProducer (
    private val userChangeLogTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, UserChangeLog>
    private val kafkaProperties: MizenKafkaProperties
) : NotificationProducer{

    @Bean
    fun connector(pf: ProducerFactory<String, Any>): SmartLifecycle {
        return object : SmartLifecycle {
            override fun stop() {}
            override fun start() {
                pf.createProducer().close()
            }

            override fun isRunning(): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    override fun sendUserChangeLog(message: UserChangeLog) {
        userChangeLogTemplate.send(kafkaProperties.userChangeLogTopic, message)
    }
}
```